# Using the same AdMob units in different fragments

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to implement AdMob into an Android App. The app has 1 activity(MainActivity) and in this activity I have 10 fragments. I would like to display a banner ad in each fragment. Can I use the same ad unit for all the fragments or it will be necessary to create an ad unit for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one Banner Ad Id for one Application. Just create string in string.xml and use the same in application. Like this -

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="ad_banner">ca-app-pub-903891699798xxxx/244573xxxx</string>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_banner" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wasn't sure what's the best practice in order to avoid having the AdMob account blocked.

Comment: I would like to know one more thing.. Can I use the banner ad in every single fragment? Or is better to use the banner ad just on the activity and above it to have a fragment transaction, so the banner will show just once? Because right now I added the banner on each fragment so when I do the fragment transaction the banner loads again.

Comment: It would be great if you use in every fragments... As it will show different ads every time... I am also following same approach... Normally I add banner on each activity/fragments

Comment: Great! I just noticed that the ads are different everytime when the fragment loads. I just wanted to make sure that everything will be fine and the AdMob account will not be affected. Thanks again for your explanation!